# Best practises for model classes injection (Angular)

Tags: angular

i have read the Angular documentation about the class injection but i can't understand which of these practices are better. To be more specific: if i have the following model class

```
export class Documents{  
private documentNumber:string; 
private countryIssuingDocument:string;   
private documentExpirationDate:string;
private documentIssuingOffice:string;

}
```

and i want to inject it

```
import { Component ,Output,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

import {Documents} from "../../model/document.model";

@Component({
selector: 'document-screen',
templateUrl: 'document-screen.html'
})


export class DocumentScreen {

constructor(private documentData : Documents) { 
}

}
```

is it better to do that using the new keyword or by declaring the model class in providers array as above. I think it is better to declare my model class in the providers array because in this way I'll have a singleton architecture. Am i right?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should only inject "singleton" classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model objects contain the data of that type. You definitely dont need a single object , you might be having many models of the same type. So its not a good idea to use dependency injection.

Use dependency injection only for services which have logic and sometimes have data which will be shared across components.

Comment: It's not clear from the OP how exactly the model is being used. How can you be sure that 'it's not a good idea'? Looks more like an opinion with unclear argumentation (this is why 'best practice' opinion based questions are considered off-topic).

Comment: Fair enough. Singleton model classes looks like a service to me. Service used only to store data. But from the description, it looks like a class defined to be used in multiple places. You have every right to downvote my answer :) but this need not be an opinionated answer, it can be answered quantitatively by checking angular docs if the question is clear.

Comment: To add to this answer ... Normally a model class is used as a 'type', not as an injectable service. And if all of the properties of this class are private ... nothing you use it with or inject it into will be able to use any of these properties.

Comment: Thank you guys...it's complicated but seems to be more clear than before